# how to have \tag, \text and cases environment like things in eqnarray

Tags: math-mode, agutex

I have this journal template that insists that I do not use `amsmath` in any way and forces me to use `eqnarray`. I am very used to `amsmath` and have things like cases environment, `\tag`, `\text`, etc. in my code. How to have those in `eqnarray`?

The template has its own class/style files... cant figure out how to add those here... but a search for "agu latex format" should give all easily...

Comment: Good job finding a valid pretext for asking a question about `eqnarray` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Default LaTeX includes the `\cases` command from plain TeX which has the rather non-LaTeX syntax:

```
\cases{x  & if $x>0$\cr
       -x & otherwise\cr}
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
  \label{eq:f}
  f(x) &=& \cases{x,&if \( x>0 \)\cr -x,&if \( x\le 0 \)\cr}\\
  \label{eq:g}
  g(x) &=& \cases{\sin(x),&if \( -1<x<1 \)\cr
  \cos(1-x),&otherwise.\cr}
\end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

`\text` can be replaced by `\mbox` or `\parbox`, but you will have to take care of some sizing yourself.

It turns out that a replacement for `\tag` is provided by the class file `agutex.cls` (at least the Feb 9, 2008 version):

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{agutex}

\lefthead{A. N. Author}
\righthead{Article Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
  \label{eq:f}
  f &=& x + y\\
  \label{eq:h}
  h &=& x - y\specialeqnum{h}
\end{eqnarray}
Equations (\ref{eq:f}) and (\ref{eq:h})

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry for late answer :) was cooking and texing simultaneously and the food needed more of my attention :) ..... The ideas do work fine  and I found that \mathletter works in place of \tag.....  Please add the tag of agutmpl with this question (as I cant) and lots of geo people who tex will be really thankful :D